# Foreach string in php?

Tags: php

Im sure the answer is all over the web but I am not sure of the proper way to search for this.

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {

      foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {

          echo '<li>'.var_dump ($field['type']).'</li>';

      }

}
```

This dumps a list of strings.

```
string(6) "switch"
string(6) "switch"
string(4) "text"
string(4) "text"
string(8) "textarea"
string(6) "switch"
string(9) "radio_img"
string(9) "radio_img"
string(10) "multi_text"
```

I want to add one more foreach and that is, foreach "switch" or whatever string desired in the above list of strings.

So something like

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {

      foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {

            foreach ($field['type']['switch'] as $string) {

                //Loop through all switches 

            }

      }

}
```

This is a new to me and I couldnt find the answer with google, not sure how to specify a string value and iterate each one.

**The Operation:**

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {
    foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {
        if($field['type'] == 'switch') {
            echo '<div class="'.$field['id'].'-stackoverflow">mycontent</div>';
        } 
    }
}
```

This will output something like

```
<div id="main-stackoverflow">mycontent</div>
<div id="layout-stackoverflow">mycontent</div>
<div id="colors-stackoverflow">mycontent</div>
<div id="fonts-stackoverflow">mycontent</div>
```

Then I will use jQuery to display the appropriate div in the appropriate page, it's an options panel and there are options hidden, when main option is selected then the main-stackoverflow div will be visable. This is just a rough desc.. thanks guys for helping, I wish I didnt have to ask such an easy question the idea was in my head the whole time, but it's nice to get others input.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to handle those fields that have the type "switch" and ignore everything else?

Comment: What you will do with those switch strings..??

Comment: build content inside the foreach, so that there is a block of code foreach "switch"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of third `foreach`.Try like

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {

    foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {
        if($field['type'] == 'switch') {
            echo $filed['type'];
            // Or even increment an counter to display how many times it occurs
            // DO $new_arr[] = $field['type']['switch'];
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah so this only outputs each field type switch.. I had this in mind while working on it, but I let it pass as I figured this couldnt be the way... looks like it is though..

Answer (score 1):

Use switch instead of another foreach

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {
    foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {
       switch ($field['type'])
       {
           case "switch":
               //do something
               break;
           case "textarea":
               //do something
               break;
           case "multi_text":
               //do something
               break;
           // add other cases...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I am using a plugin that is written similar to this, I am developing something on my own similar to the plugin and I didnt even think to use it like this... thanks this is useful to me.

Comment: I really like this answer and it would be perfect for me here but I just need one field type to run. I want to save this as I am sure I will be using this in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve by looping through strings?

You could count them and do a for-loop.

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {

  foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {

        foreach ($field['type']['switch'] as $string) {

            if($string == "switch"){
                $switch_counter++;
            }
            // ...

        }
        for($i=0; $i<$switch_counter, $i++) {
            // do something
        }

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$controls = array();
foreach ($sections as $key => $inside) {
    foreach ($inside['fields'] as $key => $field) {
       $controls[$field['type']][] = $field;
    }    
}

var_dump($controls);
```